# SQL Databinding to Dropdown Lists in Repeaters C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, data-binding

Ok guys, so I am trying to bind data into a dropdown list from c#. I am getting a Null error when trying to enter the data into the DDL's.  I am using this code for the front end.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterHardDrives" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidHardDrivesPackageDefaultID" runat="server" />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidHardDrivesPackageDefaultPrice" runat="server" />
                                <span>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbHardDiskPrice" Text="$00.00/mo"></asp:Label></span><label>Hard
                                        Drive:</label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddHardDrive" DataTextField="ItemName" DataValueField="ProductItemID" runat="server" CssClass="lidropdown">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ShowHarddriveInfo" ImageUrl="/_Images/server_configurator_helpbutton.png"
                                    OnClick="lnkShowHarddriveInfo_OnClick" /></div>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbHardDrivesPrice" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                        <br />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

for the backend I am trying to load a dynamic number of Dropdown lists into the repeater then databind them all with the same data.

```
  public void PopulateHardDrives(int intSupportedDrives)
  {
    PreloadHardDriveRepeater(intSupportedDrives);

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstrname"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Prod_SelectIDNamePriceByCategory", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryCode", "Hard Drive");
    DataTable dtHardDrives = new DataTable();
    using (conn)
    {
      conn.Open();
      SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      dtHardDrives.Load(dr);
      ViewState.Add("dtHardDrives", dtHardDrives); 
    }

    foreach (RepeaterItem riHardDrive in RepeaterHardDrives.Items)
    {
      DropDownList ddHardDrives = (DropDownList)riHardDrive.FindControl("ddHardDrives");
      ddHardDrives.DataSource = dtHardDrives;//program gives NULL exception error here(object not set to instance of object however it know the count of the rows it is supposed to be pulling)
      ddHardDrives.DataValueField = "ProductItemID";
      ddHardDrives.DataTextField = "ItemName";
      ddHardDrives.DataBind();
      Label lbHardDrive = (Label)riHardDrive.FindControl("lbHardDrivesPrice");
      lbHardDrive.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToDecimal("0.00"));
      if (riHardDrive.ItemIndex != 0) //We do not want to allow None to be selected on the main drive
      {
        ddHardDrives.Items.Insert(0, "None");
      }
    }
  }

and last but not least the function to setup the dynamic amount of DDL's looks like this 

     private void PreloadHardDriveRepeater(int intSupportedDrives)
    {
        int[] intArrDisks = new int[intSupportedDrives];
        for (int intDiskCount = 0; intDiskCount < intArrDisks.Length; intDiskCount++)
        {
            intArrDisks[intDiskCount] = intDiskCount;
        }
        RepeaterHardDrives.DataSource = intArrDisks;
        RepeaterHardDrives.DataBind();
    }
```

I am calling a list of populate functions in a !page.isPostBack if statement and the only one that is not getting the data is this one with the Drown Lists.  It gets the number of Rows(18) from the database, but it it throwing a Null error(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) I have seen quite a few people have been running into this error while googling the problem, however I could not find a solution that worked for me. The PreloadHardDriveRepeater function seems to work fine when run alone it loads the correct amount of DDL's onto the page.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your control is "ddHardDrive":

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddHardDrive" DataTextField="ItemName" DataValueField="ProductItemID" runat="server" CssClass="lidropdown">
```

and your code is looking for "ddHardDrives"

```
riHardDrive.FindControl("ddHardDrives");
```

This would be easy to notice if you debugged into the function and looked at your variable values right before the exception is thrown.

Comment: lol ok well that worked wonderfully(no wonder none of the examples I found worked). thanks for lending me your eyes